# How to set environment variables for anacron?

Tags: environment-variables, anacron

I'm currently tinkering with anacron 2.3 on a Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) installation.
I have been trying to make use of the START_HOURS_RANGE and RANDOM_DELAY env vars.
My /etc/anacrontab looks like this:

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
START_HOURS_RANGE=3-5
RANDOM_DELAY=30

# These replace cron's entries
1    5    cron.daily     nice run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7    10    cron.weekly     nice run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly    15    cron.monthly nice run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
1    0    test.job    echo 'TEST JOB'
```

The thing is, when I manually run anacron using

```
sudo anacron -s
```

The test job is executed immediately, even though I'm outside the start time range and there is a random delay associated.

I don't know what else to do to reproduce the behaviour described in the manpage for anacrontab(5)

I already thank you for any help that you could give me.

Goodbye,

Nicolás Carrasco Stevenson

Comment: If you see this before me: do a `grep START /etc/anacrontab` and post the results. If it shows nothing it is not supported on Ubuntu. No idea why it would not though ;) And if it does the manual page is wrong :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ubuntu manpage for anacrontab](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/anacrontab.5.html) states:

> Environment assignment lines are of the form:
>
> **VAR = VALUE**
>
> Spaces around VAR are removed.  No  spaces  around  VALUE  are  allowed (unless  you  want them to be part of the value).  The assignment takes effect from the next line to the end  of  the  file,  or  to  the  next assignment of the same variable.

[Redhat manpage for anacrontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/anacrontab) states:

> Environment assignment lines are of the form:
>
> **VAR = VALUE**
>
> Spaces around VAR are removed. No spaces around VALUE are allowed (unless you want them to be part of the value). The assignment takes effect from the next line to the end of the file, or to the next assignment of the same variable. The enviroment variable START_HOURS_RANGE sets the time frame, when the job could started.

I have a sneaky suspicion that `START_HOURS_RANGE` is NOT used in Ubuntu. The Ubuntu man page does not mention these parameters. This is a RHEL/CentOS Linux v6.x feature.

---

Proof is in the pudding:

```
rinzwind@discworld:~$ grep START /etc/anacrontab
rinzwind@discworld:~$
```

So yes, unsupported on Ubuntu.

---

Even more pudding!

START_HOURS_RANGE was added in `anacron-2.3-68`.

Ubuntu 13.04 uses...

```
$anacron -V 
Anacron 2.3
```

Comment: Damn, I didn't even noticed the manpages to be different. I just skimmed over them and assumed to be the same behaviour on both distros. If this is case would cross-compiling the CentOS source let me use those variables?? (with the woes from cross-compiling that is)

Comment: @NicolásCarrasco even better: find anacron version 2.3-68+ We use  2.3-19

Comment: Isn't the number after the dash, like "-68", a distribution-specific version number?